# Receiving an image in php via http post request from iOS

Tags: php, ios, http

I am trying to send an image from an iOS device to a php script. I am not getting an error on the iOS side, so I believe the problem is with my php script. I am new to php so please forgive me. Here is the php script:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999); 
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;


if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
} else {
    echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 300000) {
    exit("Your file is too large."); 
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
    $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   //Not necessary, I was using these
    $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was 
    $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   //going wrong.
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo "http://www.iroboticshowoff.com/dir/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
}
?>
```

And in case anyone knows much about iOS, here's the code I use to send the image:

```
// Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.
NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"1.0"] forKey:[NSString stringWithString:@"ver"]];
[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"en"] forKey:[NSString stringWithString:@"lan"]];

// the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
NSString *BoundaryConstant = [NSString stringWithString:@"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy"];

// string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ
NSString* FileParamConstant = [NSString stringWithString:@"file"];

// the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/upload.php"];


// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];
```

I found both of this on stackoverflow, but from my understanding the iOS is working properly and the php should place the photo in the root directory on my server.

Comment: Good book for those new to PHP: http://www.sitepoint.com/books/phpmysql5/

Answer (score 2):

The [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array holds much useful information.  You can (and should) use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to print out the contents.  Here is a script that works to upload files.  Maybe you can adapt the design for your own needs.

```
<?php // RAY_upload_example.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// MANUAL REFERENCE PAGES YOU MUST UNDERSTAND TO UPLOAD FILES
// http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
// http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php
// http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

// MANUAL PAGES THAT ARE IMPORTANT IF YOU ARE DEALING WITH LARGE FILES
// http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize
// http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
// http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time


// PHP 5.1+  SEE http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

// ESTABLISH THE NAME OF THE 'uploads' DIRECTORY (MUST ALREADY EXIST)
$uploads = 'RAY_junk';

// ESTABLISH THE BIGGEST FILE SIZE WE CAN ACCEPT - ABOUT 8 MB
$max_file_size = '8000000';

// ESTABLISH THE MAXIMUM NUMBER OF FILES WE CAN UPLOAD
$nf = 3;

// ESTABLISH THE KINDS OF FILE EXTENSIONS WE CAN ACCEPT
$file_exts = array
( 'jpg'
, 'gif'
, 'png'
, 'txt'
, 'pdf'
)
;

// LIST OF THE ERRORS THAT MAY BE REPORTED IN $_FILES[]["error"] (THERE IS NO #5)
$errors = array
( 0 => "Success!"
, 1 => "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"
, 2 => "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"
, 3 => "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"
, 4 => "No file was uploaded"
, 5 => "UNDEFINED ERROR"
, 6 => "Missing a temporary folder"
, 7 => "Cannot write file to disk"
)
;




// IF THERE IS NOTHING IN $_POST, PUT UP THE FORM FOR INPUT
if (empty($_POST))
{
    ?>
    <h2>Upload <?php echo $nf; ?> file(s)</h2>

    <!--
        SOME THINGS TO NOTE ABOUT THIS FORM...
        ENCTYPE IN THE HTML <FORM> STATEMENT
        MAX_FILE_SIZE MUST PRECEDE THE FILE INPUT FIELD
        INPUT NAME= IN TYPE=FILE DETERMINES THE NAME YOU FIND IN $_FILES ARRAY
        ABSENCE OF ACTION= ATTRIBUTE IN FORM TAG CAUSES POST TO SAME URL
    -->

    <form name="UploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size; ?>" />
    <p>
    Find the file(s) you want to upload and click the "Upload" button below.
    </p>

    <?php // CREATE INPUT STATEMENTS FOR UP TO $n FILE NAMES
    for ($n = 0; $n < $nf; $n++)
    {
        echo "<input name=\"userfile$n\" type=\"file\" size=\"80\" /><br/>\n";
    }
    ?>

    <br/>Check this box <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" name="overwrite" /> to <strong>overwrite</strong> existing files.
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <?php
    die();
}
// END OF THE FORM SCRIPT



// WE HAVE GOT SOMETHING IN $_POST - RUN THE ACTION SCRIPT
else
{
    // THERE IS POST DATA - PROCESS IT
    echo "<h2>Results: File Upload</h2>\n";

    // ACTIVATE THIS TO SEE WHAT IS COMING THROUGH
    // echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_FILES); var_dump($_POST); echo "</pre>\n";

    // ITERATE OVER THE CONTENTS OF $_FILES
    foreach ($_FILES as $my_uploaded_file)
    {
        // SKIP OVER EMPTY SPOTS - NOTHING UPLOADED
        $error_code = $my_uploaded_file["error"];
        if ($error_code == 4) continue;

        // SYNTHESIZE THE NEW FILE NAME
        $f_type    = trim(strtolower(end    (explode( '.', basename($my_uploaded_file['name'] )))));
        $f_name    = trim(strtolower(current(explode( '.', basename($my_uploaded_file['name'] )))));
        $my_new_file
        = getcwd()
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        . $uploads
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        . $f_name
        . '.'
        . $f_type
        ;
        $my_file
        = $uploads
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        . $f_name
        . '.'
        . $f_type;

        // OPTIONAL TEST FOR ALLOWABLE EXTENSIONS
        if (!in_array($f_type, $file_exts)) die("Sorry, $f_type files not allowed");

        // IF THERE ARE ERRORS
        if ($error_code != 0)
        {
            $error_message = $errors[$error_code];
            die("Sorry, Upload Error Code: $error_code: $error_message");
        }

        // GET THE FILE SIZE
        $file_size = number_format($my_uploaded_file["size"]);

        // IF THE FILE IS NEW (DOES NOT EXIST)
        if (!file_exists($my_new_file))
        {
            // IF THE MOVE FUNCTION WORKED CORRECTLY
            if (move_uploaded_file($my_uploaded_file['tmp_name'], $my_new_file))
            {
                $upload_success = 1;
            }
            // IF THE MOVE FUNCTION FAILED
            else
            {
                $upload_success = -1;
            }
        }

        // IF THE FILE ALREADY EXISTS
        else
        {
            echo "<br/><b><i>$my_file</i></b> already exists.\n";

            // SHOULD WE OVERWRITE THE FILE? IF NOT
            if (empty($_POST["overwrite"]))
            {
                $upload_success = 0;
            }
            // IF WE SHOULD OVERWRITE THE FILE, TRY TO MAKE A BACKUP
            else
            {
                $now    = date('Y-m-d');
                $my_bak = $my_new_file . '.' . $now . '.bak';
                if (!copy($my_new_file, $my_bak))
                {
                    echo "<br/><strong>Attempted Backup Failed!</strong>\n";
                }
                if (move_uploaded_file($my_uploaded_file['tmp_name'], $my_new_file))
                {
                    $upload_success = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    $upload_success = -1;
                }
            }
        }

        // REPORT OUR SUCCESS OR FAILURE
        if ($upload_success == 2) { echo "<br/>It has been overwritten.\n"; }
        if ($upload_success == 1) { echo "<br/><strong>$my_file</strong> has been saved.\n"; }
        if ($upload_success == 0) { echo "<br/><strong>It was NOT overwritten.</strong>\n"; }
        if ($upload_success < 0)  { echo "<br/><strong>ERROR: $my_file NOT SAVED - SEE WARNING FROM move_uploaded_file() COMMAND</strong>\n"; }
        if ($upload_success > 0)
        {
            echo "$file_size bytes uploaded.\n";
            if (!chmod ($my_new_file, 0755))
            {
                echo "<br/>chmod(0755) FAILED: fileperms() = ";
                echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($my_new_file)), -4);
            }
            echo "<br/><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$my_file\">See the file $my_file</a>\n";
        }
    // END FOREACH ITERATOR - EACH ITERATION PROCESSES ONE FILE
    }
}
```